# Dwarf Fortress World Gen

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm trying to generate a very specific map: one with an arctic ocean, a volcano, and preferably a taiga (or other frozen, wood-filled land).

I've managed to generate a couple of coastal volcanoes so far, (including one with a sub-ocean magma pipe. *that* was a fun embark -- 5 minutes of "cave in has occurred" as water became obsidian and then fell to the bottom of the magma sea) but they're never close enough to the poles to be in an arctic ocean. (I have a strong desire to acquire War Walruses, you see, so I simply *must* have an arctic biome :P )

Is there any way I can decrease the temperature on an already generated world? How can I increase the number of Cold or Freezing squares on each map?

Comment: +1 for War Walruses. http://rockpapercynic.com/index.php?date=2009-06-08

Comment: I hate to trample on anyone's dreams, but doesn't this http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010%3aKennel#Trainable_Animals indicate that walrus (walrusses?) can't be trained for war?

Comment: I have modded the RAWs to allow this. But by default? No.

Comment: Ah. I should have guessed DF was being extensively modded. Because it's just not challenging enough in its raw form...

Comment: There was an in-built tool called world painter or something similar. I believe it could do the things you want. May want to dig in that direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So from what I gather is that you want to create a specific map or decrease the temperature on an already created map.  I don't know the latter but I can help with the former:

1. Open up DF
2. On the main screen select Design New World With Parameters
3. Select one of the presets and press the <kbd>e</kbd> key
4. Scroll down till you see the following (should be the second page):

[image]

5. Change the Maximum Temperature and Minimum Volcanism values

   - good values for Temperature are ~45
   - good values for Volcanism are >50
6. Finally, to ensure a good Taiga you'll want to play with the Rainfall parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't worked in my experience (as I've tried what you suggested several times before you suggested it). What I wound up with was a world where there is a sharp border of Cold/Freezing squares, (as opposed to the gradual gradiant a "more normal" world gen would probide) but not actually a greater percentage of cold squares.

Comment: @Raven if you're running into sharp boarders you need to change the X and Y-Variance.  The Variance dictates the range between squares in the X and Y directions.  A lower Variance should create a more gradual gradiant